# Browser based SQL tool for end-user data manipulation?

Tags: mysql, web-applications

I am looking for a browser based tool (or a rapid development environment which could allow us to build a tool) which would allow users to edit data in MySQL tables. We would like to allow users to insert/delete rows, edit cells. Usability features like column sorting, or limiting entry in cells to a list of choices shall be possible.

It would be awesome if the tool allows customization (via php, javacript, python etc), user permissions, db version control (or backups).

We are looking for this sort of tool as we lack good db programming expertise.

Edit: users will not be able to create/delete tables, but only enter/remove data.

Comment: You're looking for PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: It sounds like the goal is allowing CRUD using an "Access-like approach" over an *existing* schema; I focused the title as such.

Comment: You're right. PHPMyAdmin would not only be too technical, but it is also possible to accidentally delete tables or do other sorts of harm.

Answer (score 3):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is probably the best there is for MySQL. But that is designed for DB admins not for end users.

Comment: Key point is **not for end users** .. of course, "fsvo" and "ymmv". In addition, it doesn't have the other "Access-like" support requested.